# Cancel long running operation on client cancel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, cancellation-token

I started my first project with asp.net core and razor pages.
On a client request, a long running database operation will be started.
Now i want to recognize, when the user leaves the website, so the database operation can be cancelled.

I've tried it with a cancellationToken, but it will never be cancelled.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostReadAsync([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var messages = await _logMessageService.GetLogMessagesAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    return new JsonResult(messages.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

The function get called by an Telerik Kendo UI Grid.
Can you tell me, why the cancellation token don't get cancelled, or what other options I have to detect a abortion by the client?

**Edit 1**

I pass the Token through to this function call of a NpgsqlCommand:

```
var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: AFAIK only stop/refresh can be handled, see https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: Have you tried to use the `HttpContext.RequestAborted` cancellation token? Like this: ```var messages = await _logMessageService.GetLogMessagesAsync(request, HttpContext.RequestAborted);```

Comment: It's impossible to say without being able to see your log message service. Cancellation tokens aren't magic, there has be code somewhere that actually checks the token status and aborts when it's cancelled. Simply passing it into a method doesn't achieve anything unless it's actually being utilized by that method during the work.

Comment: Hey Chris, I pass the token to a NpgsqlCommand and call the function ExecuteReader.

Comment: Hey Rufo and Alberto, as in Rufos link metioned, my cancellation token parameter will automatically bound to to the HttpContext.RequestAborted token. So this doens't get cancelled either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer myself after some more research.
The problem is a bug in IISExpress as mentioned here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5239#issuecomment-323567952

I switched to Kestrel and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel IO bound i.e. task which is running long , following is code that you can do which i got form the C# with CLR book.

Design extension method for task as below.

```
private static async Task<TResult> WithCancellation<TResult>(this Task<TResult> originalTask,
CancellationToken ct) {
   // Create a Task that completes when the CancellationToken is canceled
   var cancelTask = new TaskCompletionSource<Void>();
   // When the CancellationToken is canceled, complete the Task
  using (ct.Register(
     t => ((TaskCompletionSource<Void>)t).TrySetResult(new Void()), cancelTask)) {
    // Create a Task that completes when either the original or
    // CancellationToken Task completes
    Task any = await Task.WhenAny(originalTask, cancelTask.Task);
    // If any Task completes due to CancellationToken, throw OperationCanceledException
     if (any == cancelTask.Task) ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
  // await original task (synchronously); if it failed, awaiting it
  // throws 1st inner exception instead of AggregateException
 return await originalTask;
}
```

as given in following example code you can cancel it by using extension method designed above.

```
public static async Task Go() {
   // Create a CancellationTokenSource that cancels itself after # milliseconds
   var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000); // To cancel sooner, call cts.Cancel()
   var ct = cts.Token;
   try {
    // I used Task.Delay for testing; replace this with another method that returns a Task
     await Task.Delay(10000).WithCancellation(ct);
     Console.WriteLine("Task completed");
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled");
  }
}
```

In this example cancellation done based on given time , but you can call cancellation by calling cancel method.